# Warning: require_once(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, class, xampp

I'm including PHP Class like that 
`require_once(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]).'\xampp\htdocs\aclass\classfile.php');`

but when i executed the code thow a error

> Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\htdocs\aclass\classfile.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\aclass\index.php on line 2
>   Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\htdocs\aclass\classfile.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\aclass\index.php on line 2

**fileclass.php**

```
    <?php  
class Test{
    public function hello(){
        echo "hello every one";
    }
}
```

**testclass.php**

```
<?php

require_once (realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]).'\xampp\htdocs\aclass\classfile.php');
$var=new Test();
$var->hello();
```

thank you in advance!!

Comment: You're most likely typing the wrong path. Just in the code you've shared you mention `classfile.php` and `fileclass.php` :-?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DOCUMENT_ROOT is already in \xampp\htdocs, so you can skip that part:

```
require_once(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]).'\aclass\classfile.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to shift site from server to local then it may also occur
just check if your **htacces** file is in public copy that to the main **root directory**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).